Design pattern for Interface with implementing classes no longer requiring all methods
I have an interface AService which has 2 methods, and this interface is implemented by two different classes. One of the methods is directly called from an another service by calling on an AService instance (the actual implementation is given by a factory method).
interface AService {
    method1
    method2
}

class Impl1 implements AService {
    //both methods implemented
}

class Impl2 implements AService {
    //both methods implemented
}

class AnotherService {

    void process() {
        AService service = factory.getService(...);
        if (some logical condition) {
            service.method1();
        }
    }
}

The situation changed over time and now one of the classes should not need method1 any more, whereas the other class still needs it. At the moment, I kept the implementation body empty and method1 declared in the class no longer needing it, as it is still called from the service depending on the result of the factory method.
What is the cleanest way to handle this? Would it be better to introduce an instanceof check in the service to check that the instance is of that particular type, and then cast it and call the method, and remove method1 from the common interface?

Please take the time to format your code when you post it - code without any indentation is really hard to read.

Do Impl1 and Impl2 implement an interface? They are not marked.

Yes they do, and I edited the question accordingly.

Extends is wrong word. Also, your Question is confusing. I would rewrite to be more simple and specific. MCVE.

If your process will only ever call method1, then you should have an interface that only specifies this.
Sometimes you cannot change the interface so the you have to decide what would happen if method2 was te be called unexpectedly. Either "do nothing" which still means that that you could have to build an appropriate return value, or throw an exception that the operation is not supported. If either of the cases is common you could have them as defaults in the interface but with the risk of implementations missing that they should decide if they want to implement the method enough.
